# Stop Mongod server from Python Script

Tags: python, mongodb, subprocess, pymongo

I have a python script which starts the mongod service.
The script look like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([dbLocation +"\\"+"mongod", '--dbpath', dataPath])
```

How do i kill this daemon in safe/graceful manner once i have done my job with MongoDb?

Also,it would be great if someone can suggest some other alternatives to start the `mongod` instead of a `subprocess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest your run MongoD as a service instead, so there is no need to start and stop Mongod in your Python instance.

On a Linux environment you can start a Mongod service like this after specifying the `dbpath` in `/etc/mongod.conf`:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

and stop it using the following command:

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

If you are using Windows instead, you can install the service using the following command with the `dbpath` set in your `mongod.cfg` file:

```
"C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg" --install
```

and start it using:

```
net start MongoDB
```

and stop it using:

```
net stop MongoDB
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jaco.It helped a lot :)